# Identify invariants

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, invariants

Invariants are very important in problem solving but I am not clear on what are some approaches to identify them easily.
Example:
If I have something like the following:

```
i = i + 1;
j = j + 1;
```

It is pretty clear that the diff of the variables `i - j` will remain constant regardless of the actual values of i and j.
But when we have more complicated cases e.g.:

```
i = i + 3;  
j = j - 1;
```

what would be some ways to figure out the invariant?
In the above case I could see some things by writing out small numbers to notice the pattern but couldn't formalize it to `3j + i` as being the invariant.
Any suggestions how to approach this?

Comment: There's an article [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/183815) that may or may not help.

Comment: `j - (i + 2) = 0`?